# How to pre-fill a bootstrap markdown editor?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, markdown

I am using the bootstrap markdown and I was wondering how can I make the text area content out of a parsed HTML.

The markdown works fine when I add something, later when I have to edit what I have added, I have to fill the text area with what I had while adding.

Is there any way I can make the markdown out of parsed HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I managed with the obvious solution of saving the text-area content which is the markdown and used the same while editing.